# Button content into the Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

[image: Entry with 6 Button]

my question is how can i implement it when i click the button â it will paste inside the Entry â as character or more of those buttons

I don't need the code for it. What i need is the idea to do this.

Comment: Unless you specify what are you using for your GUI it will be difficult to answer. You should also include a self-contained testable code snippet that we can work on.

Comment: good grief people! This question isn't so bad as to merit so many down-votes (there are 7 down-votes as I write this). The question is poorly written but it's still quite easy to come up with an answer. I think a score of -1 is sufficient to get the point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to do it for two buttons, using a tkinter Entry widget:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.text = Entry(self)
        self.text.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.but1 = Button(self)
        self.but1["text"] = "a"
        self.but1.bind("<Button-1>",  self.do)
        self.but1.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.but2 = Button(self)
        self.but2["text"] = "b"
        self.but2.bind("<Button-1>",  self.do)
        self.but2.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.pack()

    def do(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        self.text.delete(0, END)
        self.text.insert(0, widget["text"])

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

**Edited:** eliminated root.destroy() that is  not needed. See also Bryan Oakley comments below for an alternative strategy using the `command` argument instead of the `bind` method

Comment: It's rather unusual to use a binding on a button rather than to use the `command` property of the widget.

Comment: The problem on your code is I muss click either a or b. But what my problem is that i have the opportunity a plus b can be even including from the keyboard characters to combine entered

Comment: well your post ask for an idea of how to do it, and on the other hand this especification was not indicated in your post... anyway it is easy, delete self.text.delete and it will work as you want

Comment: @BryanOakley I only know the basics of tkinter, so the code could be a bit simple or bizarre for experts. The problem I had was that I didn't know the way of sending the event to get the button object (as in `widget = event.widget`) in the `do(self,event)` method using `command`. Thats why I used bind (and because my expertise is in wxPython where bind is the way to go). Could you give a hint of how to do the same with command?

Comment: thank you so much @BryanOakley i muss learn the events. This is my first real programm on pyhton I have started for 2 weeks ego  to learn python

Comment: @joaquin: one way to do it is something like `self.but1 = Button(self, text=u"\u00c3", command=lambda c=u"\u00c3": self.do(c))
`, then edit self.do to be `def do(self, c): self.text.insert("insert", c)`. Also, you don't need the final destroy; by the time that code executes the window will already have been destroyed.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, I see. That strategy however seems more verbose. You have to write the text twice so it is redundant, more prone to errors and a bit harder to maintain, specially if the OP decide to increase the number of her keyboard-missed characters for the GUI. With bind, the button property to show, in this case `text`, is controlled in one line in a method, contrarily, with `command`, if you decide to print a different property of the button you should change it one by one, so you loss some flexibility(?)...

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks also for the hint on destroy. Edited. I got the code skeleton from tkinter docs [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm) where destroy was used. I see now that the docs also say this is only for some particular situations.

Comment: @Joaquin: there are several ways to not have to write the text twice. For instance, instead of passing `c`, you can pass the widget itself and use it just like bind: `lambda w=self.but1: self.do(w)`.